# Adding numbers and subtracting multiples

Tags: java, loops

So I am working on this problem where user enters the number X and result is the sum of all the numbers between 0 and X calculated in this way:

1. multiples of 7 and multiples of 11 are not included in the sum.
2. but multiples of both 7 and 11 are included for ex: 77

for example:

user enters X >> 80

total sum >> (0+1+2+3+....77) **-** (7,11,14,21,22....77) + (77) = result

```
import java.util.Scanner;
    public class testadd {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.print("Please the number greater than 77");
           // int a = 0;
            int b = keyboard.nextInt();
            int sum = 0;

            int s = Math.min(0, b);
            int e = Math.max(0, b);

            System.out.println(s);
            System.out.println(e);
            int x=0;
            for(int i=1; i<e; i++){
                if(i%7 ==0 || i%11 ==0){
                    x=x+i;
                    System.out.println(x + " values of x");
                }
            }

            while (s <= e) {
                sum += s;
                s++;
            }

            System.out.print("The sum of the numbers between " + 0 + " and " + b + " is " + sum);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why are you using `Math.min` and `Math.max`?  If `b` is greater than 77, then `Math.min(0,b)` is always 0, so there's no reason to complicate things by using `Math.min`.  Similarly for `Math.max`, but I'll let you figure out what `e` would be set to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need a single loop to go over all the numbers from `1` to `e`. An elegant way to check for numbers that are divisible by `7` or `11` but not by both is to use the `^` (exclusive or) operator:

```
long sum = 0;
for (int i = 1; i <= e; ++i) {
    if (!((i % 7 == 0) ^ (i % 11 == 0))) {
        sum += i;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are not including numbers divisible by 77 in your sum. Your for loop should look like this (you don't need the while loop) :

```
        for (int i=1; i<e; i++) {
            if((i%77 == 0) || (i%7 !=0 && i%11 !=0)) {
                x=x+i;
                System.out.println(x + " values of x");
            }
        }
```

i.e. add `i` to the total if either `i` is divisible by 77 or `i` is *not* divisible by `7` and `11`.